# React Native : Find device rotation angle (Orientation)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, orientation

I'm trying to get the device rotation angle for **Android** in **React Native**.

Is there any useful library? I found some for only iOS, and some not worked for me, checked the Stack Overflow but the questions about it is kinda old.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [react-native-sensors](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors)?

Comment: @Abe i just tried it and here is my code : https://imgur.com/a/GwMyAFP , I'm rotating my phone and i get values like this. Something should be wrong